# Is there any xCode alternatives for homebrew?

Tags: xcode

For Homebrew to work I need to download xCode, but I do not want to download a 40+ gigabyte app. Is there any alternatives for xCode I could use.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a "full" Xcode installation.

hoembrew requires the Xcode command line tools which could be downloaded from Apple directly.

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools

By the way, Xcode should be around 10GB not 40. :)

Comment: Thank you for the letting me know that i could use xcode command line tools instead of xcode but when i do check my applications i see xcode and it is 32gb and then when you factor ios device support and simulators it get well over 40gbs.